# Trying to Identify short story with teleportation where the original is copied and secretly killed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, teleportation

Science fiction short story (~15 pages) from 60s-70s ish time period where teleportation is possible. To teleport, a person is given what they think is a sedative (to keep them from moving during teleportation supposedly), except its actually a poison - they are just copied elsewhere and the original is incinerated. The story is about a person who the poison does not work on, so that person wakes up later and now there's a problem because there's two of him, but also the company (whatever is doing the teleportation) was hiding the fact of killing the original from the public. I don't know what else happens, just this premise. I think it was from one of those Isaac Asimov's scifi magazines or a similar bunch of scifi stories. Help please?

Trying to identify short story of secretly killing people and copying them elsewhere, sold to the public in the story as 'teleportation'.

Comment: This "fake teleportation trick" reminds me of the 2006 movie _"The Prestige"_, which is based on a novel of Christopher Priest's called [_"The Prestige"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prestige) too. But that seems to be a longer book, and the main characters are two magicians trying to outshine each other, not one of the "transferred" people.

Comment: Sounds like "think like a dinosaur" but that was the 90s.

Comment: I feel like I've read someone ask this question before. None of the stories listed in the literature section at https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DestructiveTeleportation mention poison as the method of doing away with the original, though.

Comment: Same trope as think like a dinosaur  - while it may not be the story the OP wants readers of this post may enjoy the story (#80 on the list) https://archive.org/details/SETheater/S.E.T._82_Think_Like_a_Dinosaur_Part_1.mp3

Comment: Also episode 7×08 of the 1990s Outer Limits https://archive.org/details/TheOuterLimits1x0102TheSandkings

Comment: Think Like a Dinosaur is a short story that was made into a good Outer Limits (1990s version IIRC): aliens resembling dinosaurs provide technology which creates a distant copy of a human and the original is destroyed. When this does not work, the human operator of the sending station is told by the dinos that he must "balance the equation" by killing the woman (original person).

Comment: Was it definitely poison? I got a memory of a story like that but the people were killed by electrocution when they pulled the lever to teleport